# Interrupt priorities

Tags: microcontroller, embedded

I have never considered interrupt priorities very important in my embedded programming. Is it correct? Should I pay attention to the priorities of the interrupts while programming? How much does it impact the software? It is generic question and not related to any controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its entirely application specific.

**Situation**: You setup 2 interrupts, one timer interrupt(every 1ms maybe) for keeping  track of timeouts,pulse generation etc, and another interrupt for maybe everytime you receive data via uart.
Now,assume you have not set priorities for your interrupts and a data is received via uart, but also at the same time, the timer interrupt also needs to occur(1ms). Which interrupt will you service? You know for certain that timer interrupt cannot wait.If you choose to service the uart interrupt,your timings will go haywire.Hence you need to set a higher priority for the timer interrupt compared to uart interrupt.

Hence it is essential you study your requirements and constraints and decide whether its ok if all interrupts can have same priorities(its ok to service one after another even if all occur almost at same time) or some interrupts must have a higher priority over others(they cannot wait).

Comment: So let us say the UART interrupt happens just fraction time before the 1 ms interrupt then it has to wait till the UART interrupt is finished, then also the same issue may happen. Is it possible that it can stop the  UART interrupt and handle the 1ms interrupt? In that case will there not be data missing.

Comment: No No... Even if uart interrupt occurs while your in the timer ISR,after you complete your timer ISR it will enter into uart interrupt. To avoid data overflow in uart for such cases,ul need hardware or software flow control

Comment: Then will it not miss the data. As the contrroller is processing 1ms interrupt.

Comment: ok, now i understand controller will store the data in buffer, and the data will be overwritten if you cannot read it before new data.

Comment: Thats wat i said. If u dont want to lose data,use flow control(ACK for every byte,CTS,Rx FIFO etc).

Comment: Yes.Correct. If u have a fifo size of 16 bytes, wait for ACK before u send next 16

Answer (score 1):

The answer is specific to the application.  Do you have one or more interrupts that are more important than the other.  Ones that have to be handled the fastest or with the least latency?  And others, that if they have some latency well that is okay?

That determines whether or not you care.  Microcontroller or microprocessor, not related to any specific one, although if the specific one does not support priority, but you need it well you cant use that one.